# Merging different length data frames with their mean values in the overlapping observations

Tags: r, rbind

For exemple I have 3 dataframes:

```
test.df1
        date  x  y  z
1 1998-01-01 10 10 10
2 1998-02-01 10 10 10
3 1998-03-01 10 10 10
4 1998-04-01 10 10 10
5 1998-05-01 10 10 10
6 1998-06-01 10 10 10

test.df2
        date x y z
1 1998-03-01 5 5 5
2 1998-04-01 5 5 5
3 1998-05-01 5 5 5
4 1998-06-01 5 5 5

test.df3
        date x y z
1 1998-05-01 1 1 1
2 1998-06-01 1 1 1
```

I want to merge them together so that the new data frame would have the number of rows as in the largest data frame (`test.df1` in this example), and when the dates overlap, the mean value of the variables is added to the new data frame. In the example above, the new data frame should have `4` columns and `6` rows.

`x`,`y`, and `z` for `1998-01-01` and `1998-02-01` should remain `10`;

for `1998-03-01` through `1998-06-01` should be `7.5` (mean of 10 + 5);

and for `1998-05-01` and `1998-06-01` should be `5.33` (mean of 10 + 5 + 1)

Is there a way to do it in r?

```
dput(test.df1)
structure(list(date = structure(c(10227, 10258, 10286, 10317, 
10347, 10378), class = "Date"), x = c(10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10), 
y = c(10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10), z = c(10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 
10)), .Names = c("date", "x", "y", "z"), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = "data.frame")

dput(test.df2)
structure(list(date = structure(c(10286, 10317, 10347, 10378), class = "Date"), 
x = c(5, 5, 5, 5), y = c(5, 5, 5, 5), z = c(5, 5, 5, 5)), .Names = c("date", 
"x", "y", "z"), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame")

dput(test.df3)
structure(list(date = structure(c(10347, 10378), class = "Date"), 
x = c(1, 1), y = c(1, 1), z = c(1, 1)), .Names = c("date", 
"x", "y", "z"), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: It can be done, but the only method I can think of is quite convoluted.  I would query each data frame element for a matching date string field, and construct a new data frame from the mean of all of the matches.  Its fairly straight forward data frame work.

Comment: Answer: Yes, this can be done in R.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One liner in base R should get you there:

```
aggregate(. ~ date, data=rbind(test.df1,test.df2,test.df3), FUN=mean)
#        date         x         y         z
#1 1998-01-01 10.000000 10.000000 10.000000
#2 1998-02-01 10.000000 10.000000 10.000000
#3 1998-03-01  7.500000  7.500000  7.500000
#4 1998-04-01  7.500000  7.500000  7.500000
#5 1998-05-01  5.333333  5.333333  5.333333
#6 1998-06-01  5.333333  5.333333  5.333333
```

Make one big `data.frame` with all the rows using `rbind`, then `aggregate` by date so that the mean can be calculated when there are overlaps.

If you're a `dplyr` user, the same logic can be applied:

```
library(dplyr)    
rbind_all(list(test.df1,test.df2,test.df3)) %>% 
  group_by(date) %>% 
  summarise_each(funs(mean))
```

Answer (score 2):

My approach would be to first bind the dataframes with duplicates, then use the dplyr package (when doing colMeans, make sure to exclude non-numeric columns):

```
library(plyr)
test.merge <- rbind(test.df1, test.df2, test.df3)
test.merge <- ddply(test.merge, ~date, function(x){
  colMeans(x[,-1])
})
```

**Output**:

```
        date         x         y         z
1 1998-01-01 10.000000 10.000000 10.000000
2 1998-02-01 10.000000 10.000000 10.000000
3 1998-03-01  7.500000  7.500000  7.500000
4 1998-04-01  7.500000  7.500000  7.500000
5 1998-05-01  5.333333  5.333333  5.333333
6 1998-06-01  5.333333  5.333333  5.333333
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `dplyr` and `tidyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
test.df1 %>% left_join(test.df2, by = "date") %>%
             left_join(test.df3, by = "date") %>%
             gather(var, val, -date) %>%
             mutate(var = substr(var, 1, 1)) %>%
             group_by(date, var) %>%
             summarise(val = mean(val, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
             spread(var, val)
Source: local data frame [6 x 4]

        date         x         y         z
      (date)     (dbl)     (dbl)     (dbl)
1 1998-01-01 10.000000 10.000000 10.000000
2 1998-02-01 10.000000 10.000000 10.000000
3 1998-03-01  7.500000  7.500000  7.500000
4 1998-04-01  7.500000  7.500000  7.500000
5 1998-05-01  5.333333  5.333333  5.333333
6 1998-06-01  5.333333  5.333333  5.333333
```